# Como inserir cookie neste codigo

Tags: javascript

Gente eu tenho um código que faz um link ficar verde por 10 segundos e depois fica azul, o único problema é que se eu atualizar a pagina dentro desses 10 segundos ele volta tudo de novo. 
Então eu queria saber como fazer para que a ação continue de onde parou mesmo depois de atualizar, veja o código:

```
<a id="id1" href="https://br.answers.yahoo.com" onclick="myFunction(event)" target="_blank">Clique Aqui</a> <br/><br/>

<script language="javascript">
    function myFunction(s) {
        var id = s.target.id;

        document.getElementById(id).style.color = "green";
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById(id).style.color = "blue";
        }, 10000);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Boas, podes sempre tentar usar localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer que ela continue indefinidamente até que você a exclua, você pode fazer isto com html5, ou se você quer que esqueça os dados ao fechar o navegador também.

INDEFINIDAMENTE:
// Armazenar

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
```

// Receber

```
var lastname = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

// Remover

```
localStorage.removeItem("lastname");
```

TEMPORARIAMENTE
// Armazenar

```
sessionStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
```

// Receber

```
var lastname = sessionStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

// Remover

```
sessionStorage.removeItem("lastname");
```

Comment: Como eu coloco no meu codigo? tenho que colocar outro nome no lugar de lastname? (Sou leigo ainda)

Comment: O nome do que você se refere, por exemplo, vou me referir a um nome eu colocaria localStorage.setItem("nome", "Leonardo");